# How to convert UI simple dropdown to clickable?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm with UI simple dropdown like,

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav pull-right bg-screen white dropdown user days" style="margin:8px -4px 0 0;">
  <div id="timezonepicker" class="ui simple dropdown item dropdown-toggle button timezone-dropdown" dropdown style="background: #444444 !important;box-shadow:none !important;">
    <span class="text" style="max-width: 132px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">{{selectedTimeZone}}</span>
    <div class="menu">
      <div id="timezonepickermap"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

above specified code is injected as directive like,

Now it's working fine when hover.. need to convert this as clickable drop-down.

Can anyone help me how to convert this...?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using some Javascript and adding an onclick action, so whenever its clicked the selected option will have its value returned?

What are you actually trying to achieve? Why not just use a select dropdown?

Comment: I have done scripting to display map, when hover on menu. But now it need to click to open instead of hover. Not to do much script i need to covert this into click menu.